# Mounting LUKS encrypted drive

Tags: mount, encryption, disk, luks, cryptsetup

I have a LUKS encrypted drive which I can boot from on more modern UEFI bios machines but not older devices. Every machine in my house is an older device.
Instead, I've tried to mount the thing in Ubuntu but no luck so far. Ubuntu asks for a passphrase and the 'Disks' gnome utility shows the drive but no option to mount it and it's not accessible in the file browser.
I've attempted to mount it in the terminal using various commands but this is the sort of thing I get:

```
 sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdc3 cryptroot
 Cannot use device /dev/sdc3 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).
 sudo umount /dev/sdc3 
 umount: /dev/sdc3: not mounted.
```

Which sends me around in useless, frustrating circles. The drive appears to be 'mapped' (not sure what that means in this context) to '/dev/dm-0' but this cannot be mounted using 'mount' or 'cryptsetup' either: I don't even know what it's for, it doesn't appear useful.

I've read that I might have to have the dm-crypt kernel module installed (tried seeing if it was with modprobe dm-crypt, which returned nothing, which I assume mean that module isn't installed) but I couldn't find any information about how to installed dm-crypt as a kernel module and anyway, that might just be more time wasting.

So, I'm missing something. Is there some magic utility that allows ubuntu to do something useful with this disk or is this some sort of security feature? (if so, have to say, don't much like it). I would like this to 'just work' if possible.

Comment: You have LVM, you do not mount partitions but volumes which with LVM are inside one partition. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621 and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you Oldfred, that did the trick. Specifically, this:


sudo pvscan                 #Use this to verify your LVM partition(s) is/are detected.
sudo vgscan                 #Scans for LVM Volume Group(s)
sudo vgchange -ay           #Activates LVM Volume Group(s)
sudo lvscan                 #Scans for available Logical Volumes
sudo mount /dev/YourVolGroup00/YourLogVol00 /YourMountPoint