# Ubuntu 18.04 / Windows 10 dual boot error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, testdisk

So I've been trying everything from Boot-Repair to TestDisk to try and fix boot errors after trying to install an older version of Ubuntu. I had both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and using grub bootloader before everything went kaboosh, and now they both don't boot.

I'm linking Pastebin info [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fFSsZ6vcMn/).

Comment: Your boot info indicates it's a UEFI system apparently with all the entries correctly installed in the ESP. So, you should be able to boot either one - Windows alone or Grub with options for Ubuntu and Windows - by selecting the proper options in the boot order at the firmware (UEFI).

Comment: You used full drive LVM install which erased Windows.With LVM (and encryption?) you need to mount an encrypted install before running Boot-Repair. You are showing some issues and may need dosfsck on ESP and fsck on your LVM, if it is not just mount issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/865872#865872 & this shows running fsck on LVM, just skip resize commands. https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu