# How to configure a GRUB boot entry to boot encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, bootloader

I have multiple hard drives and multiple partitions on each hard drive. On my second hard drive I installed only Ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption. During the installation of Another OS I destroyed the GRUB configuration and the encrypted Ubuntu won't boot anymore. I tried to boot it via grub rescue, but I could only boot the non-encrypted OSs. Now I try to add an entry via [Grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), but I can't figure out how to do so correctly. This is what I tried:

[image]

Can anyone help please and tell me how to configure it correctly? It is definitely on /dev/sdb, but not sure if sdb1 or sdb2. I don't know how the default installation of Ubuntu partitiones the drives.

Comment: For the report to show everything, you probably need to manually mount the LVM and decrypt your install. Then it should work correctly. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZGcmZjZv5M/   Can you do something with it?

Comment: I am  not seeing any LVM volumes. You have an UEFI system, but various BIOS installs of grub. And only sda is gpt which is normally used with UEFI. You have have grub installed to MBR of sda, sdc & PBR/BS of sdb1. Grub should not be installed to PBR of a partition. You show a Windows boot partition on sdc2, but cannot tell if sdc3 is missing boot files or hibernated. Since sdc is MBR, Windows must be BIOS boot. Since UEFI hardware, better to start over, reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode using gpt on all drives. Make sure you backups are up to date.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I can't backup my stuff, because I can't decrpyt the encrypted Ubuntu 20.04 on sdb. I was able to start Ubuntu installed on sda4 and update the boot manager. It found the Ubuntu on sda4 and Windows, but not the encrypted Ubuntu on sdb. What is PBR/BS?

Comment: PBR is partition boot sector/record and BS is Boot Sector. Both refer to the first sector of a partition which is just like the MBR or first sector of a drive. BIOS systems cannot directly boot from PBR, so grub rarely installed to PBR. And Windows has its own code in PBR, so grub is never installed to NTFS PBR. And most systems are now UEFI, which does not use MBR, only ESP - efi system partition for booting. Encrypted installs use LVM, you are not showing any LVM?

Comment: Very weird... So the encrypted OS is suddenly gone? Is there any way to find out?

Comment: When you using encryption, the most important first thing you do it create a very good backup procedure. Recovery from encrypted disk is just about impossible unless you can see it & mount it using your passphrase. That is the entire purpose of encryption. I am not seeing it, but this is how you mount it. For mounting encrypted see first few lines:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu