# boot-repair is asking for a repo to install grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

...but I've no idea what repo it needs.

I'm running boot-repair from the Ubuntu 20.04 live USB stick, have successfully installed boot-repair and see this every time I run it:

Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi-amd64-signed] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (mapper/vgubuntu-root). Then try again.

I'm not clear on a couple of points here (and would very much appreciate help). 1. Where do I find such a repository? and, 2. If this grub package is essential to boot-install, why isn't it included in the boot-install live USB (which I've also tried, with the same result)?

The first question is practical; the second more philosophical. If somebody can put my mind to rest over either or both of these I'd be very grateful.  And if more information is needed I'll be happy to follow up here.

Meanwhile, current boot details here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MtfxvwwV6W/

LATER

I've also tried installing grub-efi-amd64 independently of boot-repair, using the Synaptic Package Manager. This doesn't seem to impress boot-repair in the least---it still insists on running the install itself from a repo whose location it teasingly refuses to reveal.

--
Chris

Comment: Boot-Repair report also is missing many parts it normally shows. Those parts are all in / (root). Or did you not decrypt your install, so Boot-Repair could see / . Repository is in /, and it normally shows grub.cfg, fstab & other files in /.

Comment: Thanks, @oldfred. I'm not clear what you mean by "decrypt your install". My failing to boot Ubuntu installation wasn't encrypted. Are you saying that the Boot-repair USB I also tried is encrypted? My ultimate fix was a complete re-install. But I'd certainly appreciate your help to my understanding of Boot-Repair for the future.

Comment: If not encrypted, the / partition had some sort of issue as not correctly mounted. Usually Boot-Repair will ask to mount LVM or RAID types. Often Boot-Repair will do a basic fsck if the ext4 partition reports an issue. Often first to try is fsck. Examples of using e2fsck: https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 But with LVM it is more complicated as you have to use LVM tools to mount partitions in the LVM. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu