# fsck does not return anything

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

My DELL laptop on Ubuntu 20.04 is currently getting stuck on boot after it crashed. I tried to run fsdk on a ubuntu live USB, but when I run the command on my linux filesystem partition `sudo fsck -y -f /dev/nvme0n1p3` I only get the following output :

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
```

The fdisk -l command return 3 partitions :
/dev/nvm0n1p1 of 513M, EFI System
/dev/nvm0n1p2 of 732M, Linux Filesystem
/dev/nvm0n1p3 of 952G, Linux Filesystem

Here is the output of sudo parted -l :

```
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: USB Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 62.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      2699MB  2703MB  4096kB               EFI


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  999GB  999GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1023MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  1023MB  1023MB  linux-swap(v1)


Error: /dev/mapper/luks-fddac026-db32-4798-9083-b5a8665f7202: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)                                   
Disk /dev/mapper/luks-fddac026-db32-4798-9083-b5a8665f7202: 1023GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: KXG50ZNV1T02 NVMe TOSHIBA 1024GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1305MB  768MB   ext4
 3      1305MB  1024GB  1023GB
```

Comment: Is p2 a boot partition and then p3 really LVM? Post this: `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: @oldfred I put it on the question

Comment: I do not know LVM, but that is what you have. Is it also encrypted? You have to use live installer & mount LVM ( & decrypt if encrypted) and then run fsck on the ext4 volume. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621
For mounting encrypted see first few lines:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu

Comment: `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` should do it.